# Is it possible to loophole your way into getting a permanent guardian of faith?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, duration, permanency

[*Guardian of faith*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/guardian-of-faith) says:

> The guardian vanishes when it has dealt a total of 60 damage.

Because of this, could you:

1. Have the guardian attack something with a good Dex save
2. Assume the thing succeeds
3. If not, attack it again (it succeeds, the Guardian dealt 30 damage)
4. Attack an object twice because objects fail Dex saves

Conclusion (4.5): The Guardian has dealt 70 damage. This means it can never do a total of 60 damage. You now have a guardian for the rest of 8 hours.

5. Repeat daily

Actual conclusion: You have a permanent *guardian of faith*.

Would this work?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No. The guardian doesn't vanish when it **deals** a total of 60 damage, it vanishes when it **has dealt** a total of 60 damage. As soon as it deals 70 damage, it will have dealt 60 damage, and will therefore disappear.

Comment: Dealing a total of 70 damage requires that it has dealt a total of 60 damage.